# Create a vector from the elements of other vectors

Tags: r

I have 4 vectors `a, b, c and d`. I would like to create a vector `v` which in the first  iteration i want to use the first element of `a, b, c and d` and in the second I want to create the v by the second element of `a, b, c and d` , and so on. How can I do this in R? for example:

```
     a = c(1, 3, 6, 7)
     b = c(2, 4, 6, 8)
     c = c(4, 6, 8, 9)
     d = c(-1, 3, 6, -3)
```

and the end for example I should have 4 different `v` vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   V <- mapply(FUN=c, a, b, c, d, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

To access the results, you'd use `V[[1]]`, `V[[2]]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
m <- matrix(c(a, b, c, d), nrow = length(a))
```

Then index by row to get the desired vectors, for example, `m[1,]`